# How to find a variable if I have its address in memory?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

in my application I am getting an exception: `MyApp(38431,0xa004ffa0) malloc: *** error for object 0xa08be760: pointer being freed was not allocated`

Is there a way for XCode to show me where this pointer is? How can I find where the problem is?

I know that I can type info line*[address] and it may show me where the line is. But now it doesn't work for me.

How can I get a number of line or name of a variable where exception is being thrown?

Thank you in advance,
Ilya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling free() without calling malloc().  Look for uninitialized pointers.  If you're using a debugger (gdb) you should be able to type "bt" for "backtrace" and this will show you the stack at the time the error occurs.

Comment: He's probably not calling malloc if he's using Objective-C. He's probably releasing at the wrong time.

Comment: Yeah; I'm not an Obj C guru.  Just going off the exception.  Either way, most likely an uninitialized pointer if it's non-null but bad.  Could be double free too, I suppose but that should be hard to do in Obj C, right?

Answer (score 3):

in gdb try

```
bt
```

to get more information about when the error happens. Attempting to free non allocated memory is a common bug and gdb+xcode provides many tools to help you figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Could you please tell me what are the tools and how to use them? Probably you can point me an article or a book that has the information?
This is really a problem for me - I have to spend hours finding where an error is in my code.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to put a breakpoint a `malloc_error` this will cause your program to break when the message in question is printed.

You can also use the following method, to find the point of allocation from the address:

1. Set [MallocStackLogging, MallocStackLoggingNoCompact](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/MallocDebug.html) environments to 1.
2. Run the program and once it prints out the line use [malloc_history](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/malloc_history.1.html) from shell to find out the stack trace of the allocation: `malloc_history <pid> <addr>`.